# Using command line options with crosswalk

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

I have an IntelliJ module called xwalklib. It contains the jars, native libs, resources. I have another module called xwalktest in which I have my activity. It all works fine but I can not get the command line stuff to work.

I have added an assets folder to xwalktest (I also tried adding it to xwalklib) and in there I've put a file called xwalk-command-line and the content of the file is this:

```
  xwalk --disable-web-security --enable-remote-debugging
```

however I can't remote debug the browser and I'm pretty sure the disable web security flag has not affected it yet. I've tried using the debugging extension for chrome to debug it and I've also tried going to the ip:9222 which I'm assuming is the default port and I got nothing.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention I'm using crosswalk-webview-6.35.131.13-arm

Comment: Finally figured out how to turn on debugging `XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);`

Comment: Ever have any luck with the disable security?  or any other XWalkPreferences?  I can't find a list of the full set.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to do what I needed and had to move on.

Comment: Thanks @mntgoat, I found the same thing last night at like 2 am.  How disappointing.  I love the full-featured-ness of the webclient in terms of its web-side capabilities, but in terms of controlling/configuring the embeddable to work as I need it to, it has almost no options/configurability.  So sad.  Back to the stock 4.4 WebClient...